# Fire a trigger after update of clob in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, database, oracle12c

We have a requirement where we need to fire a trigger after update of col1,col2,col3 on table t1. Problem is col3 is of type CLOB. If only col3 gets updated the trigger doesn't fire. Is there a way we can fire a trigger after update of a clob column? We are on oracle 12c.

Comment: There is a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890332/trigger-not-firing-for-one-particular-clob-column/36999775#36999775

Answer (score 0):

See [here an explanation for your issue](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4091615106025):

> Your trigger actually works -- WHEN it is fired!

But when we the lob contents it doesn't modifies the **`lob locator`** in the table itself. The row values of the table are not changing, the trigger does NOT fire for the `dbms_lob.copy` (or `write`, or `trim`, or `append`,etc. )